# What are these and why they compile: "class Tst<T extends I1, I2, I3>" and "class Tst2<T extends Cls & I1, I2, I3> {}"?

Tags: java, generics, types

Why these lines compile (SE8) and what is happening within them?

```
class Tst<T extends I1, I2, I3> {}  // why compiles?
class Tst2<T extends Cls & I1, I2, I3> {} // why compiles?
```

I understand that

```
class Test<T extends SomeClass & SomeInterface1 & SomeInterface2> {

   <T extends SomeClass & SomeInterface1 & SomeInterface2>  void genericMethod() {}

}
```

are two examples of *type intersection* (JLS 4.9. Intersection Types).

Besides a class can implement multiple interfaces (`class Test implements I1, I2, I3` )

But the code below beats me:

```
interface I1 {}
interface I2 {}
interface I3 {}

class Cls {}

class Tst<T extends I1, I2, I3> {}  // why compiles?
class Tst2<T extends Cls & I1, I2, I3> {} // why compiles?
class Tst3<T extends Cls & I1 & I2 & I3> {} // intersection types
```

Comment: Well if they compile, then they are valid Java code. So `Tst` is a generic class that take 3 type parameters.

Comment: Why do you think `T extends I1, I2, I3` is related to `class Test implements I1, I2, I3`? How would you then list multiple generic types when you use `,` equivalent to `&`?

Comment: This demonstrates the power of choosing a good name. If it was `class Tst2<T1 extends Cls & I1, T2, T3> {}` you would have understood the code immediately. Just by using a different name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
class Tst<T extends I1, I2, I3>
```

In the above case `I2` and `I3` are Generic parameters just like `T`.
They do not refer to the interfaces and you could change them to any other name you wish. (eG `class Tst<T extends I1, R, E>`)

If you were to declare a class Tst you would have to do it with 3 generic parameters:
One for `T extends I1`, the secong for `I2` and the last for `I3` for example: `Tst<I1, Object, Object>`

Answer (score 1):

Commas inside `<...>` simply indicate a formal parameter.

```
class Tst<..., ..., ..> {}
Tst<Integer, String String> tst;
```

The rest was understood. Simple.